# How to overload a super class method in a subclass in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

My super class is Materials and FictionSection class inherit Materials class. I am trying to insert a record to database.I have created seperate classes to deal with user interfaces and to deal with mysql queries. addMaterials() in materialinner.cpp is overloaded in fictioninner.cpp.To deal with graphical interface fictionsection.cpp is used. To implement the insert method functioninner.cpp is used. Once the project is compiled it gives the following error.

```
H:\c++Prac\Libro\fictioninner.cpp:33: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [4]' to binary 'operator+'
                  "values('"+ id +"','"+ copies +"','"+ shelf +"','"+ editn +"')");
                              ^
```

materials.h

```
#ifndef MATERIALS_H
#define MATERIALS_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "materialinner.h"

class FictionSection;
class JournalSection;



namespace Ui {
class Materials;
}

class Materials : public QMainWindow, public MaterialInner
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Ui::Materials *ui;
    FictionSection *fic ;
    JournalSection *journal;
    //StaffDashboard *dashbrd;

};

#endif // MATERIALS_H
```

materialinner.h

```
#ifndef MATERIALINNER_H
#define MATERIALINNER_H

#include<QString>
#include "databaseconnection.h"
#include "validation.h"

class MaterialInner : public DatabaseConnection, public Validation
{
public:
    MaterialInner();
  //  MaterialInner(QString,QString,QString,int,QString,QString);

    QString title,fname,lname,category,publisher,cost;
    int id;
    bool addMaterials(QString,QString,QString,QString,QString,QString);
    bool updateMaterials(QString,QString,QString,QString,QString,QString);
    bool deleteRecords(QString);
    bool flag;

private:


};

#endif // MATERIALINNER_H
```

materials.cpp

```
#include "materials.h"
#include "ui_materials.h"
#include "fictionsection.h"
#include "journalsection.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>

Materials::Materials(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Materials)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   // QObject ::connect(actionFiction_section,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(on_actionFiction_section_triggered()));
}

Materials::~Materials()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Materials::on_btnAdd_clicked()
{


     QString title = ui->lneditTitle->text();
     QString fnme = ui->lneditFnme->text();
     QString lnme = ui->lneditLnme->text();
      QString cost = ui->lneditCost->text();
     // int csts = cost.toInt();

     QString pub = ui->lneditPub->text();
     QString categry = ui->cmbxCategry->currentText();

       MaterialInner mat ;
        dbConOpen();
   bool flag  = mat.addMaterials(title,fnme,lnme,cost,pub,categry);
       if(flag == true)
       {
           QMessageBox :: warning(this,"Save","Data Inserted successfully");
       }
       else
       {
          QMessageBox :: critical(this,"Error","Couldn't insert reords");
       }
       dbConClose();
}
```

materialinner.cpp

```
#include <QtSql>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include "materialinner.h"

MaterialInner::MaterialInner()
{

}
/*MaterialInner :: MaterialInner(QString title, QString fname, QString lname, int cost, QString publisher, QString category)
{
    this->title = title;
    this->fname = fname;
    this->lname = lname;
    this->cost = cost;
    this->publisher = publisher;
    this->category = category;
}*/
bool MaterialInner :: addMaterials(QString ttle, QString fnme, QString lnme,QString cst, QString pub, QString cat)
{
  // MaterialInner(ttle,fnme,lnme,cst,pub,cat);
   QSqlQuery query ;


  flag = query.exec("insert into book ( material_title,auth_fname,auth_lname,cost,publisher,category )"
                    " values ('"+ttle+"','"+ fnme+"','"+lnme+"','"+cst+"','"+pub+"','"+cat+"')");
  return flag;

}
```

fictionsection.h

```
#ifndef FICTIONSECTION_H
#define FICTIONSECTION_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include"materials.h"
#include "fictioninner.h"

    namespace Ui {
    class FictionSection;
    }

    class FictionSection : public QMainWindow,public FictionInner
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit FictionSection(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~FictionSection();

    private slots:
        void on_btnAdd_clicked();

    private:
        Ui::FictionSection *ui;
    };

    #endif // FICTIONSECTION_H
```

fictioninner.cpp

```
#include <QtSql>

#include "fictioninner.h"

FictionInner::FictionInner()
{

}
bool FictionInner :: addMaterials(int id, int copies,int shelf, int editn)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
   bool flag = query.exec("insert into fiction (material_id,no_of_cpy,shelf_num,edition)"
                 "values('"+ id +"','"+ copies +"','"+ shelf +"','"+ editn +"')");
     return flag;
}
```

fictionsection.cpp

```
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "fictionsection.h"
#include "ui_fictionsection.h"


FictionSection::FictionSection(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FictionSection)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

FictionSection::~FictionSection()
{
    delete ui;
}

void FictionSection::on_btnAdd_clicked()
{
    //Accepting user entered values
 QString id = ui->cmbxId->currentText();
 int matId;
 if(!id.isEmpty())
 {
   matId = id.toInt();
 }
 QString copies = ui->lneditCopies->text();
 int numOfCpy;
 if(!copies.isEmpty())
 {
   numOfCpy = copies.toInt();
 }
 int shelfNo = ui->spinbxShelf->value();
 int edition = ui->spinbxEditn->value();
 dbConOpen();
 flag = addMaterials(matId,numOfCpy,shelfNo,edition);
 if(flag == true)
 {
      QMessageBox :: information(this,"Save","Data Inserted successfully", QMessageBox ::Ok);
 }
 else
 {
     QMessageBox :: critical(this,"Save","Data Inserted successfully");
 }
 dbConClose();
}
```

Although I tried to find the error a lot I couldn't find it. Thank you in advance
 If I use query.bindValue() would it be correct?

```
bool FictionInner :: addMaterials(int id, int copies, int shelf, int editn)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
  //  QString string = QString("values ('") +QString :: number(id) +"','"+ QString ::number(copies)+"','"+ QString ::number(shelf)+"','"+ QString ::number(editn) '" ");
   bool flag = query.exec("insert into fiction (material_id,no_of_cpy,shelf_num,edition)"
                 "values(:matId, :cpy, :shlf, :edtn)");
   query.bindValue(":matId",id);
   query.bindValue(":cpy",copies);
   query.bindValue(":shlf",shelf);
   query.bindValue(":edtn",editn);
     return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a lot of irrelevant code for a simple error. A simple error where the message really says it all.

The problem is that you simply can't concatenate strings like the way you do. First of all, you can't "add" string literals with other string literals, secondly adding a string literal and an integer doesn't do what you expect it do do.

Since you use Qt you could use [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) and [`QString::number`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number) to construct your strings dynamically.

Example

```
QString string = QString("values('") + QString::number(id) + "','" + ...;
```

Note that once you have one `QString` object the compiler will automatically find the right conversion from character literal to `QString` so only the first string literal needs to be a `QString` object.

---

Regarding the issue about adding an integer to a string literal. A string literal is an array of read-only characters. And for any array `a` and *integer* index `i` the expression `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`. Now from this we can easily see that adding an integer to a string literal simply adds an offset to the string and gives a pointer to that offset.

Example:

```
char foo[] = "hello world";
puts(foo);  // Prints "hello world\n"
puts(foo + 6);  // Prints "world\n"
```

In the above example, the `'w'` in `"world"` is in the seventh position in the string, i.e. index 6.

Comment: But I store records in fiction table as int. So how can I modify my code to overcome the above error?

Comment: @user3279893 You did follow the link to the `QString::number` function, and read about what it does?

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the above error you can use the query.bindValue() which prevents you of converting the int input values to strings.

```
bool FictionInner :: addMaterials(int id, int copies, int shelf, int editn)
{
    QSqlQuery query;

    query.prepare("insert into fiction (material_id,no_of_cpy,shelf_num,edition)"
                 "values(:matId, :cpy, :shlf, :edtn)");
   query.bindValue(":matId",id);
   query.bindValue(":cpy",copies);
   query.bindValue(":shlf",shelf);
   query.bindValue(":edtn",editn);
   flag = query.exec();
     return flag;
}
```

Comment: ...and this solution automatically escapes the strings to prevent SQL-injections!